# Changing the 'Shipping' text in WooCommerce cart and checkout pages: [duplicate new]

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce with the Babystreet theme and I'm trying to alter the word "Shipping" on the basket page with totals.

I found some advice here on kriesi.at and http://hookr.io/themes/evolve/3.7.2/actions/woocommerce_checkout_order_review/

But am not sure of the action to add :
The hook is either "woocommerce_review_order" or "woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total"

Am really not sure because the code of my theme is :

```
    <div id="order_review" class="woocommerce-checkout-review-order">
     <table class="shop_table woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table">
       <tr class="woocommerce-shipping-totals shipping">
         <th>Expédition</th>
```

So I was hesitating between these 2 :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_review_order', 'custom_checkout_review_order' );
function custom_checkout_review_order( $fields) {
  return 'Expedition, après 25% de prise en charge';
}
```

// Hook in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_review_order' , 'custom_checkout_review_order' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_checkout_review_order( $fields ) {
$fields['Expedition'] = 'Expedition, après 25% de prise en charge';
return $fields;
}

Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 0):

Add following filters in your active theme functions.php file

This will change Shipping text in cart page and checkout page

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_package_name', 'custom_shipping_package_name' );
function custom_shipping_package_name( $name ) {
    return 'Delivery';
}
```

This will change text in order details

```
add_filter('gettext','change_shipping_text');
add_filter('ngettext','change_shipping_text');
function change_shipping_text($text) {
    $text = str_ireplace('Shipping','Delivery',$text);
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! The 1st one worked totally for my issue :D